# How to use the outer() to calculate the median between each vector?

Tags: r, matrix, vector, outer-join, median

I hope the title isn't too confusing...

Basically, I have two vectors that is each of n length. I want to transmute these two vectors to a n*n matrix (i.e. 2 vectors that contains 2 numbers each becomes a 2*2 matrix), where each position in the matrix is the median of each position of the two vectors.

For example:

```
a<-as.vector(1,5)
b<-as.vector(1,5)
```

Using `outer()` gives me a 2*2 matrix

```
  1 5
1
5
```

But, how do I fill the empty matrix with median values between each unique combination? The answer should look something like this:

```
1 3
3 5
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
 outer(a, b, FUN= Vectorize(function(x,y) median(c(x,y))))
 #     [,1] [,2]
 #[1,]    1    3
 #[2,]    3    5
```

#### data

```
a <- c(1,5)
b <- a
```

Comment: always super fast...!

Comment: ahhh...I left out the vectorize()...I was playing around with that...
Thank you again, akrun!

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  Actually, i posted after 3 mintues.  So, don't know if it qualifies for speed.  But, thanks for the vote.